# Relational Query Parse.com Javascript & Display in a Table

Tags: javascript, jquery, parse-platform, html-table, relational

```
var Level1Results = Parse.Object.extend("Result");
var query = new Parse.Query(Level1Results);
query.lessThanOrEqualTo("LevelNumber","3");
query.include("currentUser");
query.find({
success: function(results) {
//alert("Successfully retrieved " + results.length + " scores.");
// Do something with the returned Parse.Object values
for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) { 
  var object = results[i];

(function($) {
   $('#level1-table').append('<tr> <td>' + object.get('SFirstName') + '</td> <td>' + object.get('CurrentLevel') + '</td> <td>' + object.get('RightOrWrong') + '</td> + '</td></tr>');
})(jQuery);
          }
    },
    error: function(error) {
    alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
    }
    });
```

I am trying to link two classes together, one called currentUser and the other called Result, at the minute I can get all the Objects I want loaded from the Results class.. but when I try and get SFirstName from the currentUser class to display..

If anyone has any idea what silly thing I am doing wrong.. Please share!

Answer (score 0):

It's simple just use get("currentUser")

```
object.get("currentUser").get('SFirstName')
```